# Change serializer class for single method in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If I want to override a method in my viewset to change the serializer_class for only a single method, how can I do that.

I tried passing `serializer_class=CustomSerializer` but it doesn't have any effect.

```
class VoteViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Vote.objects.all()
    # Use normal serializer for other methods
    serializer_class = VoteSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Use custom serializer for list method
        return viewsets.ModelViewSet.list(self, request, serializer_class=VoteWebSerializer, *args, **kwargs)
```

Basically do the same `list` method as the inherited viewset, but use a different serializer to parse the data.

The main reason for this is because javascript does not handle 64 bit integers, so I need to return the BigInteger fields as a string instead of integer.

Answer (score 3):

Override the **`get_serializer_class(...)`** method as

```
class VoteViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Vote.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == "list":
            return VoteWebSerializer
        return VoteSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

What JPG answered is the correct way. Another thing you could do is overriding the `list` method like you are doing but modifying the default behavior using the serializer that you want.

It would be something like:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

You can check the default methods in the source code or I recommend using [Classy DRF](http://www.cdrf.co/). For example [here](http://www.cdrf.co/3.9/rest_framework.viewsets/ModelViewSet.html#list) you can see what DRF is doing in the `list` method of a `ModelViewSet` doing and use that as a starting point.